# Replace first six commas for each line in a text file

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I want to replace the first six `,` for each line in a text file using sed or something similar in linux.

There are more than six `,` on each line, but only the first six should be replaced by `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Sed doesn't really support the notion of "the first *n* occurrences", only "the *n*-th occurrence"; GNU sed has one for "replace all matches from the *n*-th on", which is not what you want in this case. To get the first six commas replaced, you have to call the `s` command six times:

```
sed 's/,/|/;s/,/|/;s/,/|/;s/,/|/;s/,/|/;s/,/|/' infile
```

If, however, you know that there are no `|` in the file and you have GNU sed, you can do this:

```
sed 's/,/|/g;s/|/,/7g' infile
```

This replaces *all* commas with pipes, then turns the pipes from the 7th on back to commas.

If you *do* have pipes beforehand, you can turn them into something that you know isn't in the string first:

```
sed 's/|/~~/g;s/,/|/g;s/|/,/7g;s/~~/|/g' infile
```

This makes all `|` into `~~` first, then all `,` into `|`, then the `|` from the 7th on back into `,`, and finally the `~~` back into `|`.

Testing on this input file:

```
,,,,,,X,,,,,,
,,,|,,,|,,,|,,,|
```

the first and third command result in

```
||||||X,,,,,,
||||||||,,,|,,,|
```

The second one would fail on the second line because there are already pipe characters.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/,/\n/;s/\n/,/7g;y/\n/|/' file
```

Translate all `,`'s to `\n`'s, then replace from the seventh `\n` to the end of line by `,`'s, then replace the remaining `\n`'s by `|`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pattern in sed: `sed 's/old/new/<number>'`

Where `<number>` is the number of times you want this pattern applied.

You can replace `<number>` with `g` to apply the pattern to all occurrences.

Comment: No, `<number>` is for "only replace the numberth match of the regexp".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -r ':loop; s/^([^,]*),/\1|/g; /^([^|]*\|){6}/t; b loop' file
```

(OR)

```
sed ':loop; s/^\([^,]*\),/\1|/g; /^\([^|]*|\)\{6\}/t; b loop' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k

$ sed -r ':loop; s/^([^,]*),/\1|/g; /^([^|]*\|){6}/t; b loop' file
a|b|c|d|e|f|g,h,i,j,k
```

*Note:* This will work only if you do not have any pipe(`|`) before that.